# update image path with words starting uppercase to lowercase chars

Tags: posts, images, mysql

I have to convert the image path to lowercase characters inside wp_posts table.

Right now, I have inside my posts this:

```
<img class="alignleft" title="my image title" alt="my image alt" src="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/My-Image-Lowercase-First-Char.jpg" width="75" height="75" />
```

And I need to update those uppercase chars in the image path to lowercase chars like this: **my-image-lowercase-first-char.jpg**.

Is it possible to do it via mysql in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the case of the paths without changing the file names themselves could break your links, depending on the server and its configuration.

But to get to the question directly, you *may* be able to do this with SQL using [MySQL's `REPLACE` and `LOWER`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html), but I would advise against it. MySQL has some regex functionality but not much. PHP's regex is better by far.

Pull your posts, loop over them, and fix the links. Run something like this:

```
function replace_cb($matches) {
  if (!empty($matches[1])) {
    return 'src="'.strtolower($matches[1]).'"';
  } else {
    return $matches[0];
  }
}
function reset_paths() {
  global $wpdb;
  // debug using a specific post ID
  // $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_content FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE ID = 128");
  // remove the where for a real run over all posts
  $posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_content FROM {$wpdb->posts}");
  $pattern = '|src="([^"]+)"|';
  foreach ($posts as $p) {
    define( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE', true );
    $p->post_content = preg_replace_callback($pattern,'replace_cb',$p->post_content);
    wp_update_post($p);
  }
}
reset_paths(); // run the function
```

`reset_paths();` beneath the function definition is what triggers it-- what actually runs the function.

But make a backup and test that thoroughly on a dev server with disposable data before you try it in production.

If you have a lot of posts you may have timeout or memory issues so watch that. If you do have problems you will have to run the function incrementally.

The assumption is that your markup is consistent. That will now replace image `URL's where the attribute is surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: Should I run this from a file via browser or should I put it inside functions.php?

Comment: Add it to `functions.php` but remove it when you are done. I stress, ___make a backup and test thoroughly___. What you are doing is at best moderately dangerous.

Comment: This is not working... Right now I have: `<img class="alignleft" title="My Title" src="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/uploads/My-Image-85-75x75.jpg" alt="My Alt" width="75" height="75" />` Any ideias why? I putted it inside functions.php and I'm on wampp localhost...

Comment: What isn't working? How is it not working? I tested this minimally and it did work for me. Did you actually _run_ the function with `reset_paths();`?

Comment: I just paste it in functions... should I add something to this function? add_action, perhaps??

Comment: @Alex : See the edit.

Comment: Brilliant! Can I run this on all posts at same time instead of doing it one by one?

Comment: Yes, it ___will___ run on all posts, hence the warning about timeout and memory issues, just remove the `WHERE ID = 128`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can use one of these plugins:
 1. http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/
 1. http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/

Just do backup before modyfying your database ;)

The other way is to do it manually:

1. Export your database to SQL (with data).
2. Use text editor to find & replace all occurences of files (it would be nice to do it with some regular expressions, I guess)
3. Import your modified database to server.

Also don't forget to change file names using FTP.

Comment: This wouldn't do the job because it needs to be done inside wp_posts table, but thanks!

Comment: I know it has to. But this plugin can modify `wp_posts` table also. It even has options to do it (find&replace in post_content, and so on). You could also try http://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/ plugin, I guess.